# How many shiny pokemon can one trainer catch in a single day before it would be questionable that the trainer may be cheating?

Tags: pokemon-go

If someone is possible, in Pokemon Go, to in one days time, in radis only,  see 53 Rayquaza catch 51 and 5 of them be shiny without cheating in any way?

Comment: this seems very opinion based and hard to answer. If you suspect a user is cheating you should report them to an admin of the game you are playing.

Comment: Like Topcode said, this would be very difficult to judge without hard evidence of cheating. I witness somebody get a shiny Groudon three times in a row. On a Lapras raid day, a buddy of mine got 12 shinies total. Both instances, no cheating was in involved

Comment: Cheating server-side mechanics is extremely difficult, and 5/51 is hardly an extraordinary result for a 1/20 shiny rate. I see nothing suspicious here.

Answer (score 4):

If this is a server-side mechanic as [John Montgomery](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/234469/john-montgomery) claims, it's unlikely there's any cheat detection for it. There may be checks in the code for *bugs* (I.e. the shiny function always returning true under some conditions because of some property of the RNG), but it's unlikely the user is going to be punished for developer mistakes. The server keeps track of all the pocket monsters, thus there's no way for a client to influence shiny rate.

Thus there's unlikely to be any check on the probability.

As an aside, millions of players play this game over billions of days of play. Thus it's elementary that someone will eventually get a one-in-a-billion shiny rate. As an aside, that rate would be getting 16+ shinies out of 51. The rate 5/51 or better has an 11% occurrence.

Comment: This should probably include that with remote raids, it is now very easy to be in 50+ raids in a single day as long as the player is willing to pay for all the remote raid passes. Before remote raids were a thing, this would have been extremely difficult but not entirely impossible.